# how to get data from query string after "=" symbol?

Tags: php

I have used below code:

```
$query = parse_url($_SERVER ['HTTP_REFERER']);
$q=$query['query'];
print_r($q);die(123);
```

The result of such code is :

```
Array ( [scheme] => http [host] => localhost [path] => /d7/tamil-nadu-floods [query] => cid=TN201501HP )
```

Then I used :

```
$q=$query['query'];
print_r($q);die(123);
```

Result of it is : cid=TN201501HP
Here just want to use cid number i.e. TN20151HP .How to get number that is after symbol "=" ?

Comment: do you mean `parse_str` ??

Comment: just try to explode it by = operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo $_GET['cid'];
```

You can use simply `$_GET[]` global varibale.

Comment: $_GET[] provides access to current request query, not http referer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can get 'TN201501HP'

```
$q=$query['query'];
$exp=explode('=',$q);
echo $exp[1];
```

Comment: What are you trying to do @RajenderRajan, have you checked your answer after 5 months or what. first accept then unaccept. Are you playing here? if you wanted you could have accepted that answer at that time only. As, both the answers were given at the same time. Please check it

Answer (score 0):

```
    $query_string = parse_url($_SERVER ['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_QUERY);

    $query = array();
    parse_str($query_string, $query);
    $cid = $query['cid'];
```

Comment: Please add a little description, what you changed to achieve the result.

Comment: I have used 2 php functions [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) and [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to get the needed result.